# C# ULONG_PTR Equivalent

Tags: c#, winapi, interop, types

I am having to pass a `ULONG_PTR` in unsafe code in C#.

I understand that the reason for `ULONG_PTR` is to allow for a single codebase for both 32bit and 64bit operating systems.

Is this a case for C#'s `UIntPtr`?  Can I be confident when passing a .Net `UIntPtr` as  an `ULONG_PTR` parameter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uintptr.aspx):

> The IntPtr type is CLS-compliant,
>   while the UIntPtr type is not. Only
>   the IntPtr type is used in the common
>   language runtime. The UIntPtr type is
>   provided mostly to maintain
>   architectural symmetry with the IntPtr
>   type

Both types are capable of storing 32-bit and 64-bit pointers. The preferred type is `IntPtr`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the MSDN description of it I would say that it should be:

> The UIntPtr type is designed to be an integer whose size is platform-specific. That is, an instance of this type is expected to be 32-bits on 32-bit hardware and operating systems, and 64-bits on 64-bit hardware and operating systems.